# How many images will you see when you view the following file in the modern browser

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone please explain why there would be 5 images. I think there should be 4 images. One before the loop and the rest after the loop execution.
My interpretation of code is as follows:
i :  0 1 2 3   4 5  6  7 
c :  0 1 2 3=0 1 2 3=0 1 
img: 1 2 3 2   3 3  2  3    Note: i am interpreting continue command as not to follow the code and go to next iteration therefore no another image is cloned/appended for the i=5 iteration

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function do_something() {
        var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var theImg = document.createElement("img");
        theImg.src = "cat.png";
        theBody.appendChild(theImg.cloneNode(true));
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++, count++) {
            if (i == 5) continue;
            if (count == 3) {
                count = 0;
                theBody.removeChild(theBody.lastChild);
            } else {
                theBody.appendChild(theImg.cloneNode(true));
            }
            if (i > 7) break;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="do_something()"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: 5 looks right to me

Comment: did you forget the image added before the loop?

Comment: Open in chrome and right click on the page and go to "inspect". Then add a break point some where in the loop and step through your code in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

A bit difficult to explain by me, but hope you know,

before loop you append a image (1),
and next 0 1 2  add 3 img,(4) 

but at 3 remove 1 so (3),

then keep going 4 add 1 img (4)

5 just pass by 

so 6 will be another 3 just remove 1 img(3)

and meet 7 add a img img(4)
but note, your last if is mean great than 7 and check at last line,

so when i become 8 still add img to body img(5)
that's why you will see 5 image at total

Comment: Thank you very much I was missing the 8th iteration part.

Answer (score 1):

First image:

```
 theBody.appendChild(theImg.cloneNode(true));
```

Let's analyze the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++, count++)
```

It has 10 counts plus our original so 11, however:

```
 if (i > 7) break;
```

Let's note that this at **the end of the code** - therefore it will actually run for #8

Reevaluating our potential total we have 9+1 = 10.

We can discard count #5 because of this line:

```
if (i == 5) continue;
```

So now our count is 9.

This next statement causes every 4 count to a) not print an image and b) remove an existing one.

```
if (count == 3)
   count = 0;
   theBody.removeChild(theBody.lastChild);
```

So 9/4 = 2. It will therefore remove 2 images and not print 2 new ones. So now we have 5

Comment: Thank you very much I was missing "Let's note that this at the end of the code - therefore it will actually run for #8" this part.